# Micro controller serial communication question

Tags: microcontroller, serial

Im relatively new to micros and have a conundrum.  My senior project  involves using a touch screen and xbee modules for wireless communication.  My question is, since both of them require serial communication, should I find a micro that has 2 serial ports, or is it possible to have both of them connected to the same serial port and select which one to communicate with?

Comment: That depends on how much time and money you're willing to throw at the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, in general, connect them to a single serial port. You'll need a microcontroller with (at least) two serial ports.

Sometimes, if you're trying to really minimise the cost of the microcontroller, you can implement a seral port using GPIO pins and I/O instructions. This can be very effective for a transmit-only serial port. But I would not recommend it for a project like this.

Answer (score 0):

Logic level serial communication doesn't normally support multiple devices. You need two UARTs.

The SPI bus supporters multiple devices which are each selected using a chip select (CS) line.

The I2C bus supports multiple devices which are selected using inband protocol addressing.